# Set OS X password using expect

Tags: macos, shell, expect, change-password

I'm trying to write a script to update the password of an OS X account to a rotating, centrally-stored value. As a prelude to learning to use tclcurl, I just want to get this prototype script working:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set mgrpassword "newpassword"  # this will become a tclcurl command later

spawn passwd manager
expect "New password:"
send "$mgrpassword\n"
expect "Retype new password:"
send "$mgrpassword\n"

puts "\nManager password changed."

exit 0
```

It runs without errors, but it does nothing; the password for the manager account remains unchanged. I've tried it with both \r and \n but that didn't make any difference. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or what steps I'm omitting?

(It will always run with admin rights; that's why there is no 'expect "Old password:"' line.)

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more `expect` statement at the end, like as follows,

```
send "$mgrpassword\r"
expect eof
```

Basically, `Expect` will work with two feasible commands such as `send` and `expect`. If `send` is used, then it is mandatory to have `expect` (in most of the cases) afterwards. (while the vice-versa is not required to be mandatory)

This is because without that we will be missing out what is happening in the spawned process as `Expect` will assume that you simply need to send one string value and not expecting anything else from the session.

Your script can be written in the following way as well which makes it robust with the use of `exp_continue`. It will make the `Expect` to run again.

```
set mgrpassword "newpassword"
spawn passwd manager
expect {
        timeout { puts "Timeout happened";exit 0}
        "password:" {send "$mgrpassword \r";exp_continue}
        eof {puts "Manager password changed"; exit 1}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that

```
dscl . passwd /Users/manager [passwordstring]
```

works a **lot** better/easier than trying to combine passwd with expect. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to resurrect, but when using the passwd command on macOS to change a password in OpenDirectory, use:

passwd -i opendirectory [user]